# Creating a barchart from histogram, python matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I have an histogram like this:

[image: Histogram]

Where my data are stored with an append in that way:

```
(while parsing the file)
{
 [...]
 a.append(int(number))
 #a = [1,1,2,1,1, ]... 
}

plt.hist(a, 180)
```

But as you can see from the image, there are lot of blank areas, so I would like to build a barchart from this data, how can I reorganize them like:

```
#a = [ 1: 4023, 2: 3043, 3:...]
```

Where 1 is the "number" and 4023 is an example on how many "hit" of the number 1? From what I have seen in this way I can call:

```
plt.bar(...)
```

and creating it, so that I can show only the relevant numbers, with more readability. 
If there is a simple way to cut white area in the Histo is also welcome.

I would like also to show the top counter of each columns, but I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have some numpy array `a` full of integers then the code below will produce the bar chart you desire.

It uses [`np.bincount`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) to count the number of values, **note that it only works for non-negative integers.**

Also note that I have adjusted the indices so that the plot centrally rather than to the left (using `ind-width/2.`).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Generate some random data.
N=300
a = np.random.random_integers(low=0, high=20, size=N)

# Use bincount and nonzero to generate your data in the correct format.
b = np.bincount(a)
ind = np.nonzero(b)[0]

width=0.8

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.bar(ind-width/2., b)

plt.show()
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: I'm getting an error because my vector a is not numpy, is: CpuData = [0]  //job_times_req = data[2].split(';')
                   // if(len(job_times_req)==6):
                    //cpu_req = job_times_req[3]  //CpuData.append(int(cpu_req))

Comment: What is `a`? A list? What's your full error Traceback?

Comment: I have edited the comment and show what is a, I'm able to print a, b, and ind, but it generate an error generating the bar

Comment: You haven't explain what `a` is at all. If `a` is a list as you insinuated it is in your original question you can simply wrap it with `a = np.array(a)` to convert it to a numpy array.

Comment: a = CpuData sorry, and cpu_req = job_times_req[3] si takend from a file. ax.bar(ind-width/2., b) still now working

Comment: Ah ok. In that case, once you've gotten `CpuData` you simply need to do `CpuDate = np.array(CpuData)` and it will convert it to a numpy array.

Comment: I have tried, still not working, strange. Here is the image of the code and the print: http://i.imgur.com/wcsyFmd.jpg?1

Comment: Try to take everything inside the red block out of the `try` loop and have it run afterwards. The problem with a `try:...except:...` with no Exception is that it hides what the error actually is.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\parse_job.py", line 84, in <module>
    ax.bar(ind-width/2., b)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 5006, in bar
    nbars)
AssertionError: incompatible sizes: argument 'height' must be length 16 or scalar